# mylib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. while linking to a shared library(.so) in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am begginer in android ndk. I am trying to load my shared library which was built following "TwoLibs" sample provided with ndk-r8d.
I get following error while loading a simple shared library in my android project

*"Compile thumb : jbmc <= jbmc.c
jni/jbmc.c:1:19: fatal error: mylib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/jbmc/jbmc.o] Error 1*

I am using following code:

## Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmylib.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := jbmc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jbmc.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mylib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

with following native C source to use the library function in my native.

## jbmc.c

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_test1_TestActivity_myfunct(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring str)
{
    str = myf(str);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
}
```

here the the library function accept any string and return another string.

I have following hierarchy for jni.

### /jni

- Android.mk
- jbmc.c
- libmylib.so

In my Test activity I am using:

```
public native String myfunct(String abc);
static{ 
    System.loadLibrary("jbmc");
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
```

I think my header can not be loaded or found. Although I have used LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) to export my headers to local path.

I am referencing Documentation available at:
**[NDK Prebuilt library support](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html)**

Comment: Compiler is unable to find 'mylib.h' which has to be present in the jni directory of your project.

Comment: i am using a prebuilt library so As per the Documentation on http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html
I can use a prebuilt library. When I know the headers for the library.